# Strip HTML tags out of this simple "trim words" function

Tags: php

I'm using the following function in a site I'm working on;

```
function trim_text($input, $length) {

// If the text is already shorter than the max length, then just return unedited text.
if (strlen($input) <= $length) {
    return $input;
}

// Find the last space (between words we're assuming) after the max length.
$last_space = strrpos(substr($input, 0, $length), ' ');
// Trim
$trimmed_text = substr($input, 0, $last_space);
// Add ellipsis.
$trimmed_text .= '...';

return $trimmed_text;
}
```

Which is then echo'd like this;

```
echo trim_text($variableContainingContent, 100);
```

Which works fine, unless within the first 100 characters of the variable is a hyperlink.

Is there a way I can strip that, and any other HTML, before echoing this function?

Comment: `strip_tags()` maybe...

Comment: http://php.net/strip_tags

Answer (score 0):

Use `strip_tags` on your return value: http://php.net/strip_tags

```
function trim_text($input, $length) {
    ...

    return strip_tags($trimmed_text);
}
```